# Is it possible to write own stream fusion in library in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have been experimenting with the Vector library to see stream fusion in action and it's a very impressive optimization. I am curious to know how difficult it would be to create my own stream fusion library? I am just wondering if there special things I need to do like use particular pragmas, etc.

Comment: Yes you can, and yes you need to use pragmas, and yes it will be difficult. Why don't you read the articles about stream fusion, and the source code for Data.Vector?

Comment: To be more clear, Data.Vector is *just* a library itself. If it didn't exist, anyone (well, anyone super smart) could write it.

Comment: See http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/ndp/haskell-beats-C.pdf for a good paper for how stream fusion can be implemented in Haskell with near- or surpassing-C performance.  Note that this was coauthored by Simon Peyton Jones, so someone super smart as @J.Abrahamson points out.  I found the paper very approachable, though.

Comment: SPJ is a fantastic writer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fusion is largely done by the your compiler's optimizer under the control of INLINE/INLINABLE and RULES pragmas.

(Is Hugs still maintained? I'm assuming no.)

Haskell doesn't assign any special meaning to those pragmas; but both Haskell compilers ([GHC](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.1-rc2/html/users_guide/pragmas.html) and [JHC](http://repetae.net/computer/jhc/manual.html#pragmas)) do, and the meaning is very similar.

So, in theory, no.  The Haskell language isn't sufficent to indicate when fusion should occur.  But, in practice, yes.  Using INLINE/INLINABLE and RULES pragmas will cause both active Haskell compilers to perform fusion during optimization.